# Yii/Bootstrap OnClick Execute MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli, yii

I'm using Yii with Bootstrap.

I'm setting up a table full of data like this:

```
$table_contents = array(
        ... irrelevant data...
        array(
            'name'=>'Action',
            'value'=>array($this, 'activateButton'),
            )       
        );
```

Creating the table:

```
$this->widget($table_view, array(
    'type'=>$table_type,
    'dataProvider'=>new CArrayDataProvider($prod_array),
    'columns'=>$table_contents,
    )
);
```

And here is my button creation function in the controller:

```
public function activateButton($data, $row)
{       
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup', array(
        'size'=>'small',
        'type'=>'inverse',
        'buttons'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Deactivate', 
            )
        )
    ));
}
```

This all works perfectly, but I'm trying to get the button to perform a MySQL update command when the button is pressed, and I'm not having any luck figuring out what property I can set to do that. What can I add to activateButton() to get it to perform a query on press?

Comment: Make ajax request onclick and perform your query on server side.

Comment: Since the buttons are dynamically created and indeterminate in number, how would I code this so I know which button was pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should add class and item id to your getter:

```
public function activateButton($data, $row)
{       
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup', array(
        'size'=>'small',
        'type'=>'inverse',
        'buttons'=>array(
            array(
                'label'=>'Deactivate',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'my-ajax-button','data-id'=>$this->id)
            )
        )
    ));
}
```

I'm not sure how to add class properly in that widget, look at documentation.

Then you can add script to your page to make ajax call:

```
$url = $this->createUrl('your/ajax/url');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('initStatus',
    "$('.my-ajax-button').on('click','body',function() {
        el = $(this);
        $.post('$url', {id: el.data('id')}, yourJsCallback(data));
    });",
    CClientScript::POS_READY
);
```

You'll get record id in `$_POST['id']`.

Pretty simple and nice.